# Checking if Point falls inside contours using pointPolygonTest always returns true in nested shapes

Tags: image, opencv, contour

I am trying to create contours which I check to see if a point falls inside but it keeps returning 1 even if it does not.

I create a black mask, Then use a set of points to call fillPoly with white which creates the this image.

[image]

I then find countours of this image using findContours. Below is the image.
[image]

This is correct. Everything seems fine.

But later I want to check whether a point falls inside the contours using pointPolygonTest(White part in the first image) but this always returns 1 or 0.

```
for point in points
  for contour in contours
     if pointPolygonTest(contour, point, false) >= 0 // this always returns 1
        terminate
```

I think the problem is because the contours are nested. How can I go about achieving this?

I want pointPolygonTest to ignore the part I crossed red because they are outside the contours.

[image]

Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

I can include code if there is a need for it but dont think it is needed.

Comment: Its a hierachy issue see [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I needed to check whether a contor has children and also check if it satisfies the children. For instance, taking the big contor. If  pointPolygonTest returns 1 or 0, check if contour has children and if so check whether it satisfies the children as well.